# Aggregate timeline between overlapping date rows in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

We are creating an data set that looks at customer usage of company's products and where there is an overlap between usage of different products, create a time range that shows the entire period which shows the usage of any product. Where is a gap between end of usage of product and a new start of purchase, that is to be shown as different journey. Sample source data below

[image]

The required output at customer Level:

[image]

Rules: 1) Since the customer 1001 have started using P11 product before the end date of P10, those should be a continuous journey and the start date should be of row 1 and end date should be of row2.

2. There is a gap between end date of row 2 and 3, i.e customer 1001 in using any product and this has to be shown as separate journey
   Basically to create aggregation at customer level per continuous acquisition time period

How can we achieve this using plain SQL. Any pointers would highly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple task for a Teradata extension to Standard SQL: NORMALIZE.

```
with cte as 
 ( 
   select NORMALIZE -- combine overlapping periods
      customer_id
     ,period(start_date, end_date) as pd
   from mytable
 )
select 
   customer_id
  ,trim(customer_id) || '-' 
   || trim(row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by pd)
  ,begin(pd) -- split the period 
  ,end(pd)   -- back into individual columns
from cte
```

As NORMALIZE works on periods only, you need to create one using `period(start_date, end_date)`. Periods include the start, but exclude the end, if your logic is different, you might have to switch to `period(start_date, end_date+1)` and `last(pd)` instead of `end(pd)`.

Comment: Thank you @dnoeth. When i apply it for the larger data set, i receive an error  """Invalid Period value constructor. The beginning bound must be less than the ending bound""". Where am i going wrong?

Comment: You probably got a row where begin and end are the same. But this is not a valid periods which include the begin and **exclude** the end. You existing data is either based on including both start and end or you got bad data. Use a `WHERE end <= start` to find the bad rows.

Comment: It was rows where there were both same. I then used period(start_date, end_date+1) and last(pd) and worked perfectly fine. Many thanks.

Comment: dnoeth can you look  into below question when you have time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71108512/summarize-data-range-based-on-column-value-when-data-is-not-sorted