# Summarize data range based on column value when data is not sorted

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to create a customer journey for period they were active for. The base data is unordered and looks as:

[image]

I want to look first for the date when the Status=Active and then the succeeding date when Status=Inactive and the pull in the period and repeat for the next instance of the appearances. the output I am looking for is to create a table that looks as below:

[image]

Any pointers on how to do in Teradata SQL would be highly helpful.

Comment: When you do not have a matching  'Inactive' for an 'Active' , do you use the default '31-Dec-99'? This will probably be for the last unmatched Active session.

Comment: Thats Right. An active session that is open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there's always a matching 'Inactive' row for every 'Active' row and only the final 'Inactive' might be missing:

```
select customerid, dt, 
   -- next 'Inactive' row, "until changed" for last row
   lead(case when status = 'Inactive' then dt end, 1, date '9999-12-31') 
   over (partition by customerid
         order by dt)
from cust
-- only return the 'Active' rows
qualify status = 'Active';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the SQL ([dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=47b3baa505b9710fbec987ecbea7c0f9)):

```
WITH active_status
     AS (SELECT customerid,
                Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    partition BY customerid
                    ORDER BY start_date) id,
                start_date
         FROM   (SELECT customerid,
                        CASE
                          WHEN status = 'Active' THEN dt
                        END "start_date"
                 FROM   cust) x
         WHERE  start_date IS NOT NULL),
     inactive_status
     AS (SELECT customerid,
                Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    partition BY customerid
                    ORDER BY end_date) id,
                end_date
         FROM   (SELECT customerid,
                        CASE
                          WHEN status = 'Inactive' THEN dt
                        END "end_date"
                 FROM   cust) x
         WHERE  end_date IS NOT NULL)
SELECT acta.customerid,
       acta.start_date,
       COALESCE(inacta.end_date, '2099-12-31') end_date
FROM   active_status acta
       LEFT OUTER JOIN inactive_status inacta
                    ON acta.customerid = inacta.customerid
                       AND acta.id = inacta.id
ORDER  BY start_date;
```

Since Teradata SQL dialect is similar to postgreSQL , I have used it in [dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=47b3baa505b9710fbec987ecbea7c0f9) . dbfiddle does not support teradata for testing.
row_number() analytical function and coalesce() which are the only significant pieces are available in teradata.